# How to insert text when the user clicks a button on my extension?

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm writing an extension that shows two items on a popup ("Hello" and "Goodbye").

What I want to do is, when the user click one of these items, insert the respective text.

For example: I'm on gedit and I want to insert "Hello". So I open the extension and then I click "Hello" and it appears on gedit.

Here's the current code:

```
this._menucontent = null;

this._mymenu = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(this._menucontent, { reactive: true });

item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_("Hello"));
this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_("Goodbye"));
this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to connect to an emit signal of your clickable menuitems, in this case the 'activate' signal:

```
    item.connect('activate', _FunctionToCall);
```

Then in the Function you need to call some kind of 'paste' action to insert your text. The Gnome3 Extension '[Drop Down Terminal](http://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/)' has a function that pastes text from the clipboard so maybe a look at it's code will give you a hint:

[github/dropdownterminal terminal.js](http://github.com/zzrough/gs-extensions-drop-down-terminal/blob/master/drop-down-terminal%40gs-extensions.zzrough.org/terminal.js)

It is using [gi.Gtk](http://www.roojs.org/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/seed/Gtk.html) to interact with the Terminal Window.